# Как последовательно читать записи из большой SQL таблицы?

Tags: sql, firebird

Есть очень большая, больше 400 млн. записей, таблица, содержащая три поля типа VARCHAR 100 каждое. Как из такой таблицы последовательно, т.е. одну запись за одно подключение и за один запрос к базе, читать данные? При этом создавать дополнительный столбец с номерами нельзя. В таблице могут присутствовать одинаковые записи. Желательно, чтобы запросы выполнялись очень быстро. (Вроде бы - это же простая операция - просто прочитать одну запись). Может быть в SQL есть какая-то неявная нумерация записей? Если мы прочитали запись, как прочитать предыдущую или следующую? База - Firebird 2.5.9.

Comment: А что такое "следующая" и "предыдущая" запись ? В реляционных БД не существует таких понятий. Таблица это куча не упорядоченных записей, нужен порядок, сами задаете его нумерацией или скажем по "больше/меньше" по строковому (желательно уникальному) значению

Comment: Таблица, о которой идёт речь, с логами. Разное ПО просто пишет в неё события INSERT'ами, первое поле - это имя и версия программы, второе - тип события, третье - параметры, которые могут отсутствовать. Логи собирались больше десяти лет. И получается, строго говоря, нет никакого способа определить порядок поступления записей в таблицу?

Comment: И что такое "одинаковые записи", они полностью одинаковы по всем полям ? С такими записями в БД работать практически не реально. Любой запрос будет видеть сразу все одинаковые, вы даже изменить или удалить одну конкретную из них не сможете. Для нормальной работы в любой таблице должен присутствовать первичный ключ. И когда он есть, то у вас и понятие порядка записей появляется и обращаться можно точно к конкретной записи

Comment: Ну если они только писались и не было ни одного апдейта то конечно вероятность что на диске они лежат в порядке записи довольно высокая. Я не знаю как конкретно фаейрбейс работает на низком уровне. И если предположить что они лежат в нужном порядке и select без order прочитает их именно в этом порядке то я вижу только один путь, за раз прочитать их все и записать в другую таблицу где все таки будет возрастающий id что бы с ними потом можно было работать. Возможно стоит сделать это одной операцией insert select

Comment: Одинаковые - да, это записи, одинаковые по всем полям. В таблице примерно 14 групп по 3.5 процента повторяющихся записей - это 14 приложений говорили, что "последняя операция выполнена успешно".

Comment: у админов есть программка - ibexpert - и они говорят, что она показывает события в правильном порядке. ... но так как они сами писали этот софт с логами - и тут выясняется такое - возможно - что информация не точная.

Comment: Ну так посмотрите как эта прокграмка работает. Мне вот интересно как она реально становится на нужную строку. И интересно как можно посмотреть логи скажем за позавчера

Comment: а там одно из полей не дата ли? можно тогда попробовать выбирать записи за одну дату и обрабатывать

Comment: к сожалению - нет, ни даты, ни номера, ни чего-то, хотя бы отдалённо похожего на порядок - нет.

Comment: А какая ценность в событиях у которых даже нет даты ? что с ними вообще можно делать.

Comment: конкретно в нашем случае необходимо строить зависимости между группами операций, выполняемых разными программами, и их параметрами, и успешностью их выполнения - и, таким образом, смотреть, какая сложная логика на границах взаимодействия программ приводит в итоге к ошибкам. и желательно это всё анализировать за всё время - потому что восемь лет назад где-то программа не тот результат выдала - а в итоге на балансе стол с другим инвентарным номером. а штрафовать завхоза за программную ошибку километровой давности - ну такое себе. но там и по серьёзнее огрехи в ПО есть.

Answer (score 2):

На питон можно реализовать такую штуку
Но скорость выполнения может зависить еще и от самой структуры бд
я знаю 3 способа для такого или же можно использовать сортировку слияния

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Firebird};HOST=<hostname>;DATABASE=<database_name>;UID=<user_id>;PWD=<password>')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM <table_name>')
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    # обрабатываем строку, например, выводим содержимое полей на экран
    print(row[0], row[1], row[2])
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Firebird};HOST=<hostname>;DATABASE=<database_name>;UID=<user_id>;PWD=<password>')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM <table_name>')
row = cursor.fetchone()
cursor.scroll(-1, 'relative')  # перемещаем курсор на последнюю строку
while row:
    # обрабатываем строку, например, выводим содержимое полей на экран
    print(row[0], row[1], row[2])
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.scroll(-2, 'relative')  # перемещаем курсор на предыдущую строку
```

```
import fdb

# Установка параметров подключения
dsn = 'localhost:/path/to/database.fdb'
user = 'username'
password = 'password'

# Подключение к базе данных
conn = fdb.connect(dsn=dsn, user=user, password=password)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Выполнение запроса и получение первой записи
cursor.execute('SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table_name')
row = cursor.fetchone()

while row is not None:
    # Обработка данных
    print(row[0], row[1], row[2])
    
    # Получение следующей записи
    row = cursor.fetchone()

# Закрытие подключения
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Так же последовательно читать записи из таблицы можно использовать операторы ORDER BY и LIMIT

Comment: Работа курсоров обеспечивается за счет хранения данных в оперативной памяти. на 400 млн строк у вас возникнут проблемы

Comment: это правда) но был вопрос вариант решения - это вариант

Comment: Возможно, подойдет следующее: Курсор может быть "serverside" и можно указать максимальное количество записей, которые нужно держать на стороне клиента. "cursor.itersize = 20000". Как пишут в документации, чтобы курсор был на стороне сервера, нужно курсору дать имя conn.cursor(name='name_of_cursor')